# Using a Dimmed Range & Cell.Row in COUNTIF Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

Afternoon all. Got a really simple one for you, that's been bugging me for about 2 hours now. Just can't seem to crack it :D

I have a ForEach going through a range of cells and setting the Formula to a COUNTIF formula... problem is, the COUNTIF needs the criteria of a dynamic range (which is set as rng2) and also the cell from the current Cel.Row located in the M column. Struggling to get my formula to work... will post a my idea that  I've tried (been jiggling with the same formula for hours now) but the text still stays red haha

```vb
    pr = WC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Range("YMS!U2:U" & pr)
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
    cel.Formula = "CountIf(Range("rng2"), " & "M" & cel.Row)"
    Next cel
    On Error Resume Next
```

Any ideas on how to get my COUNTIF formula to work with all cells in the range?

Comment: What is "rng2"? Possibly `cel.Formula = "=CountIf(" & rng.address & ", M" & cel.Row & ")"`

Comment: RNG2 is previously dimmed dynamic range where i want to search within :)

Comment: Try replacing rng with rng2 in that line above.

Comment: Why don't you share the preceding code? Is `rng2` also in worksheet `YMS`? If not, you have to specify it in the formula e.g. `... & "'OtherWorksheetName'!" & rng2.Address...`.

Comment: Couldn’t because it contains some personal info :) yes rng2 was already in the code, I was just having an issue with how to properly place everything! It was the address part I needed, never ever used that before! Works like a charm for sure, now I just have to figure out why one of my pivots deletes itself except for headers when I refresh everything! Wish me luck… thanks kindly for the help guys ☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### VBA Write COUNTIF Formula

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteFormula()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Unknown") ' adjust!
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("Unknown") ' adjust!
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("YMS")
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dws.Range("U2:U" & dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Dim dFormula As String: dFormula _
        = "=COUNTIF('" & sws.Name & "'!" & srg.Address & ",M" & drg.Row & ")"
    'Debug.Print dFormula
    
    drg.Formula = dFormula

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the equal-sign - furthermore you have to put the address of rng2 to the formula.

```
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
       cel.Formula = "= CountIf(" & rng2.address & ", M" & cel.Row & ")"
    Next cel
```